# Hange, are you a boy or a girl?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I'm being the Prof. Oak for once and ask if Hange from Attack on Titan is male or female?

I cannot remember at all if this was ever settled in the manga. The character appears female from the hair and facial features, but I can't remember ever seeing notable secondary gender characteristics.

On this matter I don't trust translations, be it official or fan-made, so references to the character with the help of pronouns don't count. Please supply clear manga scenes or anime screenshots. Statements from secondary sources like character books (if such a thing exists for AoT) or interview statements from the creator are accepted, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though they looks like a she it's still debatable.

If we look at official tumblr account of Kodansha (Publisher of AoT) we can find an answer:

> I’ve said everything I intend to say on Hange (the short version: Hange’s gender is open to whatever interpretation you care to have)

Here the [link](http://kodanshacomics.tumblr.com/post/79565073216/you-publish-attack-on-titan-right-a-friend) of the whole question.